# How to use Reactivity APIs in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to have a Drop Down Menu in my vue application. I´ve created a variable "showDropDown". Now I want to check with a v-if directive if the value of showDropDown is true. If it is true the Menu should be displayed. If a click again on the Icon of the Menu, a function should be called that changes the value of "showDropDown" to false so it is not displayed. How can I do that. I tried it with the code below, but it doesn't work. When I tried it with using vue and through cdn it worked fine.

```
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import TheWelcome from './components/TheWelcome.vue'
import MainPage from './components/MainPage.vue'
import ProfilePage from './components/ProfilePage.vue'
import FriendsPage from './components/FriendsPage.vue'
import SettingsPage from './components/SettingsPage.vue'
import SignOutPage from './components/SignOutPage.vue'

const currentView =  "mainPage"
const showDropDown = ref (false)
const imgSrcProfile = "./src/assets/defaultUserIcon.webp"
const imgSrcLogo = "./src/assets/DailyQuotes_Logo.png"

function toggleDropDown (){
  console.log("test");
  showDropDown = !showDropDown;
}
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
          <img v-on:click="currentComponent='mainPage'" :src="imgSrcLogo">
      </div>
      <div class="profile" >
          <img v-on:click="toggleDropDown" :src="imgSrcProfile">
          <div id="dropDownMenu" v-if="showDropDown">
              <a v-on:click="currentComponent = 'profile'">Profile</a>
              <a v-on:click="currentComponent = 'friends'">Friends</a>
              <a v-on:click="currentComponent = 'settings'">Settings</a>
              <a v-on:click="currentComponent = 'signOut'">Sign out</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </header>
    <MainPage/>
  </main>
</template>
```

Comment: You can't reassign a const. Refs are used to reassign value key, they cannot physically be reactive otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the [Vue documentation on reactivity](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state-1) to understand how ref works.  ref is a proxy object. You must not try to reassign the actual ref object, but instead assign to the inner `value` property.

This is how your `showDropDown` related code should look:

```html
<img :src="imgSrcProfile" @click="toggleDropDown" />
<div v-if="showDropDown" id="dropDownMenu">
  <a @click="currentComponent = 'profile'">Profile</a>
  <a @click="currentComponent = 'friends'">Friends</a>
  <a @click="currentComponent = 'settings'">Settings</a>
  <a @click="currentComponent = 'signOut'">Sign out</a>
</div>
```

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

const showDropDown = ref(false)

function toggleDropDown() {
  showDropDown.value = !showDropDown.value
}
```